# What is the condition for $u dx + v dy + w dz$ to be exact differential?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I think the condition is $curl(u,v,w) = 0$. But a book I am referring gives following condition:

$$u \Big( \frac{\partial w}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial v}{\partial z} \Big) + v \Big( \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} \Big) + w \Big( \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \Big) = 0$$

Which one of the above conditions is right?

Comment: Both of these require further conditions on the domain.

Comment: @amd what kind of conditions? I am unable to understand. Btw I was talking about $\mathbb{R}^3$ here.

Comment: A standard example of a closed form that is not exact is $-{y\over x^2+y^2}dx+{x\over x^2+y^2}dy$. Its domain is $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$, which is not simply-connected.